# SimpleXML Free memory consumed from load file

Tags: php, memory, simplexml

I am using simpleXML to parse a file (around 341 mb).
Upon loading the file, it consumes a considerable amount of RAM which is okay. My main problem is that the memory is not freed until the cron exits.

I assumed that if I unset the referenced xml object the memory reserved for the in-memory file would also be release, but this is not the case.

Is it possible to free the memory for the referenced file?

Example code (dont know if GC can help):

```
gc_enable();
$this->xml = simplexml_load_file($filePath);
$val = $this->getValues('/SOME/PATH/HERE');

foreach($val as $a) {
   $this->tags[] = (string) $a->$tagName;
}

$this->xml = null;
unset($this->xml);
gc_collect_cycles();
```

Comment: Is there another reference to some node of the XML document you've never unset (causing SimpleXML to leave the whole thing in memory)? If not, it could just be a case of the complexities of PHP's memory manager. There's a good talk on that here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sm1HUrnsxLI

Comment: No other reference, this is the whole code. It's part of a constructor, but the XML variable is only in the scope of the constructor.

Answer (score -2):

I had similar issue with pretty big XML files(i was parsing many 1-5Mb XML files imported from another system in loop) so i moved to XMLReader and wrote code like

```
$reader = new XMLReader();
$reader->open("path_to_file.xml", "UTF-8", LIBXML_NOBLANKS);
/*do some parsing(probably you'll need iterate over nodes using next). 
 * Note that if you use XMLReader then any #text nodes even 
 * only containing new lines and spaces are being read
 * unless you set option LIBXML_NOBLANKS
 */
$reader->close();
```

This at least deallocate resources allocated by LibXML and it use way less memory while processing big document.

Comment: Thank you for the input, but this does not answer my question. I am aware of XMLReader but the problem is the performance. The plus of simpleXML is the speed. It parses the whole file in 1 second.

Comment: Do you unset every node you use in your code(not just $xml object) if you keep references to them i guess they would not be freed